# Navigation using NavHostController inside oncreate of Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have use case like based on a logic i must navigate the compose screen inside Activity, i am using the NavHostController of compose below is my code, im facing the null exception in the **navController** lateinit property on accessing the navigate function

```
private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        navController = rememberNavController()
        LearEnglishTheme {
            NavHost(navController, startDestination = LoginScreenType.Login.route) {
                addLoginScreen(navController, viewModel)
                addForgotPasswordScreen(navController)
                addTrialStudentScreen(navController)
            }
        }
    }
    val showOnBoarding: Boolean = intent?.extras?.getBoolean(Constants.ONBOARDING) == true
    when {
        showOnBoarding -> {
           // another screen for showing the onBoarding Feature
        }
        else -> {
                navController.navigate(LoginScreenType.ForgotPassword.route) // Facing null pointer in here on navController
        }
    }
}
```

How to resolve this issue, i need to move to a screen on launch of activity based on login in the **when** clause

Comment: Could please explain what do you mean by i need to move to a screen on launch of activity based on login in the when clause? Like you wnat to for exemple to start with login screen if user is not loged in and if he is already logged in start with another screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do. You want to switch from MainActivity to compose screens, if I want to do it, I think you can follow a way like this

for example you can create a navigateIfNeeded function in MainActivity viewmodel for the navigation

**MainActivity VM**

```
 fun navigateIfNeeded(): String {
    
            return when {
               showOnBoarding -> {
                 ShowOnBoardingScreen.route
               }
               else -> {
                    LoginScreenType.ForgotPassword.route 
               }
            }
  }
```

You can update this function yourself, for example, you can add extra parameters, I don't know exactly what you need.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController
    var startDestination: String = ""

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _startDestination = viewModel.navigateIfNeeded()

    setContent {
        navController = rememberNavController()
        LearEnglishTheme {
            NavHost(navController, startDestination = _startDestination) 
            {
                addLoginScreen(navController, viewModel)
                addForgotPasswordScreen(navController)
                addTrialStudentScreen(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a function in MainActivity ViewModel that returns the route of your destination according to the situation you want to go to, and this will be your start destination, you will give this start destination to your NavGraph and your NavGraph will start from this start-destination, and you can edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @NewPartizal, actually I have followed your approach by passing the start destination by the screen I need, hence resolved my query.

Comment: But on launch after the splash screen, I'm facing a black screen for 2-3 secs and after that only the screen loads, can you let me know why is it

Comment: It may be due to the splash screen, maybe if your splash screen is not a splash screen api, I suggest you use the splash screen api and make the splash screen, but I'm not sure. you can read this documentation for splash api implementation in jetpack compose -> https://developersancho.medium.com/jetpack-compose-splash-screen-api-36ca40c6196b. It is recommended to use the splash api for splash screen, and in some phone versions black screen may appear, for example, I had the same problem on a redmi phone.